# Excel VBA: How do I clear data in a Variable sheet selected based on the day of the week

Tags: excel, vba

I want to clear Specific Columns in Worksheet that gets selected based on the day of the week

EG. if Monday, A1:A10 in workbook "Mon" must be cleared if Tuesday, A1:A10 in "Thu" must be cleared and so on

```
Sub Clear_Data()

Dim Sname As Worksheet
Dim myDay As Integer
myDay = Application.WorksheetFunction.Weekday(Now())
Sname = Sheets(myDay + 1).Name

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sname.Range("D4:F102").ClearContents
    Sname.Range("L4:R102").ClearContents
    Sname.Range("T4:T102").ClearContents
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This is what I have so far, but I cant get it to work right and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

The correct sheets gets chosen, via myDay, and if I add `MsgBox Sheets(myDay + 1).Name` it also returns the correct worksheet name, but when I run the Macro it gives me

> runtime error 91 telling me the Object variable or With block variable is not set

Being a VBA noob, I have no idea what it means

Comment: Change `Sname = Sheets(myDay + 1).Name` to `Set Sname = Sheets(myDay + 1).Name`

Comment: Still does not work, get Runtime-Error 424 Object required

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: Also, you don't need to use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Weekday(Now())`. You can just use: `Weekday(Now())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace:

```
Sname = Sheets(myDay + 1).Name
```

with

```
Set Sname = Sheets(myDay + 1)
```

because on Friday, `myDay` evaluates to ***6*** and the code will clear stuff on the 7<sup>th</sup> worksheet.  Make sure you really want to change the 7<sup>th</sup> worksheet and not the 6<sup>th</sup>.

Comment: Thanks, it works, The sheet I want to change is the correct one, I have 2 sheets with other data ahead of the sheets for each day